# Cannot get SDL_SetTextureColorMod to work

Tags: c, sdl-2

I am trying to change the color of the image displayed. The image contains characters in black and I want to display them in red. So I am trying to use SDL_SetTextureColorMod but it seems I am doing it wrong since the image rendered is still black. Does someone see the problem with my code?

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_Window *window;
  SDL_Renderer *renderer;
  SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(640, 480, 0, &window, &renderer);
  SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_LoadBMP("font.bmp");
  SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
  SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

  int keep_going = 1;
  while (keep_going) {
    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
      if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        keep_going = 0;
      }
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    int ret = SDL_SetTextureColorMod(texture, 255, 0, 0);
    if(ret != 0){
      printf("%s",SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  }

  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

The image I'm using:

[image]

Comment: Black is (0,0,0), you can't change it with modulation as 0 multiplied by any number is still 0. Your white background should be red though. If you want your font texture to have adjustable colour you probably should prepare texture with white text, and optionally cut background with colour key. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah thank you! I understand now. I have set the characters to white and it all works now.
In my example the background was not set to red because the image's background was transparent. Thanks for your help ! (and I should  have read the doc more carefully)